# how to pass urls, params, headers to call() in redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Theory regarding working of call() is well explained on many websites. However, I did not found any site which explains accurately with proper working example.

I have written following code:

```
export function* loadUser() {
    try {
    const user = yield call(getUser);
    yield put({type: 'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS', payload: user});

  } catch(error) {
    yield put({type: 'FETCH_FAILED', error});
  }
}
```

here, I want to send 'get' request with some parameters and some header using call() .But I don't know how to achieve it. Please, if you have time, tell it with proper working example(Codepen or jsFiddle).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you read the Redux Saga documentation you can see `call` takes a function and a spread array of arguments (comma separated):

`call(fn, ...args)`

You can use it like so:

```
const getUsers = (options) => {
  return axios(options)
}

function *fetchUsers() {
  const users = yield call(getUsers, { method: 'get', url: `https://api.github.com/users` }, {user: 'my_username'})
  console.log(users)
}
```

Pretty straight forward.

Comment: > and an array of arguments:
This is wrong. It just means you can pass arguments as separated by a comma.

See an example fo how `...args` is used here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=17&pln=5&pc=12

Comment: @dq-charlie true, updated.

Answer (score 2):

a simple call could be comma separated, yield call(fnName, param1, param2)

Answer (score 1):

call with , function name and arguments

```
call(funcname, ...args)
```